# Windows 7 Quality Rollups

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, updates, software-update

My Windows 7 laptop, which it seems hasn't been updated in a long time, is trying to install the September 2019 Quality Rollup, and failing due to an unknown error 80092004.  The troubleshooter returns this report Troubleshooter, which shows one Windows Update error as Not fixed.

[image]

If I try to install the Quality Rollup manually, should I immediately get the December 2019 Quality Rollup instead (after getting its prereqs)?  Do later Quality Rollups contain earlier Quality Rollups, or do you have to get each month's one at a time?

Edit:  Looks like the manual installation doesn't work either.  It just says "The following updates were not installed:  Security Update for Windows (KB4530734)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the December rollup will install, go with it. It includes earlier updates that may be needed and newer updates which are new or supersede older updates.

Comment: This. All Roll Ups are cumulative. That means they all have all of the previous patches as well. So if a later one installs, there is no issue whatsoever.